# Create Order issue with Rails 5 on Woocommerce Rest API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, woocommerce, ruby-on-rails-5, woocommerce-rest-api

I have a rails 5 web app that is trying to post an order back to a wordpress website using the **[woo commerce api](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-an-order)**.

The gem wrapper I am using is:

```
gem "woocommerce_api"
```

I can create an order perfectly if I hard-code one line item. However I have no idea how to add multiple line items. See below the first "working example" then see below my attempt to loop through line items.

The error response I'm getting is:

```
{"code"=>"woocommerce_rest_required_product_reference", "message"=>"Product ID or SKU is required.", "data"=>{"status"=>400}}
```

Obviously i'm not supposed to put a .each loop in the request... But I don't know any other way?

**WORKING POST REQUEST**

```
@cart_items = Cart.where(user_id: @user.id).all

data = {
  status: "processing", 
  currency: "AUD",
  set_paid: true,
  billing: {
    first_name: "#{@user.first_name}",
    last_name: "#{@user.last_name}",
    address_1: "#{@user.address}",
    address_2: "",
    city: "#{@user.suburb}",
    state: "#{@user.state}",
    postcode: "#{@user.postcode}",
    country: "Australia",
    email: "#{@user.email}",
    phone: "#{@user.phone}"
  },
  shipping: {
    first_name: "#{@user.first_name}",
    last_name: "#{@user.last_name}",
    address_1: "#{@user.address}",
    address_2: "",
    city: "#{@user.suburb}",
    state: "#{@user.state}",
    postcode: "#{@user.postcode}",
    country: "Australia",
  },
  line_items: [
      {
        :product_id => 123,
        :variation_id => 1,
        :quantity => 2
        :subtotal => "10.00",
        :total => "20.00"
      }
  ],
  shipping_lines: [
    {
      method_id: "flat_rate",
      method_title: "Flat Rate",
      total: "0"
    }
  ]
}
```

**FAILED MULTIPLE LINE ITEM REQUEST**

```
@cart_items = Cart.where(user_id: @user.id).all

data = {
  status: "processing", 
  currency: "AUD",
  set_paid: true,
  billing: {
    first_name: "#{@user.first_name}",
    last_name: "#{@user.last_name}",
    address_1: "#{@user.address}",
    address_2: "",
    city: "#{@user.suburb}",
    state: "#{@user.state}",
    postcode: "#{@user.postcode}",
    country: "Australia",
    email: "#{@user.email}",
    phone: "#{@user.phone}"
  },
  shipping: {
    first_name: "#{@user.first_name}",
    last_name: "#{@user.last_name}",
    address_1: "#{@user.address}",
    address_2: "",
    city: "#{@user.suburb}",
    state: "#{@user.state}",
    postcode: "#{@user.postcode}",
    country: "Australia",
  },
  line_items: [
      @cart_items.each do |ci|
      {
        :product_id => ci.product.woo_id.to_i,
        :variation_id => 0,
        :subtotal => ci.product.price.to_s,
        :total => ((ci.product.price.to_d * ci.quantity.to_i).round(2)).to_s
      }
    end
  ],
  shipping_lines: [
    {
      method_id: "flat_rate",
      method_title: "Flat Rate",
      total: "0"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem has to do with the use of the `each` method.

> The most important thing to remember about the `each` method is that it does not change the return value. It implicitly returns the original array.

Have a look at the `map` or `collect` methods instead, which "creates a new array containing the values returned by the block".

```
...
  line_items: @cart_items.map do |ci|
    {
      :product_id => ci.product.woo_id.to_i,
      :variation_id => 0,
      :subtotal => ci.product.price.to_s,
      :total => ((ci.product.price.to_d * ci.quantity.to_i).round(2)).to_s
    }
  end,
...
```

However, as you said using methods in data payload isn't nice to read, so I would recommend you refactor this into a variable:

```
@line_items = ...map function here...
data: {
...
  line_items: @line_items
...
```

or into an instance method in the `Cart` model.